# Opening Image File from JavaScript (doesn't work on mobile phones)

Tags: javascript, jquery, filereader

I am trying to open image files using JavaScript. It works successfully on Chrome (showing no errors), but the image refuses to show on my iPhone. Is this because the image is too large (like the DATA url is too long)?

My code uses FileReader, gets the img.src, and outputs it as an img tag as shown below:

```js
if(window.FileReader) {   //do this
  $('input').change(function() {
     $("#result").html("SELECTING IMAGE ... ... ...");
      var fr = new FileReader;

      fr.onload = function() {
          var img = new Image;

          img.onload = function() { 
              //I loaded the image and have complete control over all attributes, like width and src, which is the purpose of filereader.
              $.ajax({url: img.src, async: true, success: function(result){
                $("#result").html("<img src='ajax-loader.gif' />");
                setTimeout(function(){
                  $("#result").html("<img src='" + img.src + "' /> <br/> <br/>" + "<a href='" + img.src + "'>View in browser</a>");
                    console.log("Finished reading Image");document.getElementById('iPUT').style.opacity=0.01;
                }, 1000);
            }});
            
            
          };
          
          img.src = fr.result;
      };
      
      fr.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
      
  });

} else {
  alert("You don't support FileReader");
}
```

```html
<html><head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <title>iViewr</title>
    <!-- The style.css file allows you to change the look of your web pages.
         If you include the next line in all your web pages, they will all share the same look.
         This makes it easier to make new pages for your site. -->
    <link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
  </head>
  <body cz-shortcut-listen="true">
  <div onclick="document.getElementById('iPUT').style.opacity=0.01">
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('result').style.zoom=0.5;this.blur();">Zoom out</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('result').style.zoom=1.0;this.blur();">Zoom normal</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('result').style.zoom=1.5;this.blur();">Zoom in</button>
    <br>
    </div>
    <div id="inputDIV" onclick="document.getElementById('iPUT').style.opacity=0.5"><input type="file" id="iPUT" accept="image/*" capture="camera" style="opacity: 0.5;"></div>
    <div id="result">Please choose a file to view it.</div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>

  
</body></html>
```

You can see it in action here at: http://iviewr.neocities.org/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: better to use URL.createObjectURL() on the File (it's a blob) instead of messing around with dataURLs and callbacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the URL.createObjectURL() on the file chosen by the input, as shown below.
Credits to @dandavis.

```js
$('input').change(function(){
  var resultPreview = document.getElementById('result');
  var file = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0]; //selects the very first file
  
  var fr = new FileReader();
  
  fr.addEventListener('load', function(){
    //once the FileReader is loaded,
    resultPreview.src = fr.result;
    console.log("Finished reading Image");document.getElementById('iPUT').style.opacity=0.01;
    document.getElementById('help').innerHTML="You can choose another image by tapping the screen again.";
  }, false);
  
  if (file){ //if there even is a first file
    fr.readAsDataURL(file); //don't want to mess with Data URLs!! this calls the function above
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <title>iViewr</title>
    <!-- The style.css file allows you to change the look of your web pages.
         If you include the next line in all your web pages, they will all share the same look.
         This makes it easier to make new pages for your site. -->
    <link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
  </head>
  <body>
  <div onclick="document.getElementById('iPUT').style.opacity=0.01">
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('result').style.zoom=0.5;this.blur();">Zoom out</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('result').style.zoom=1.0;this.blur();">Zoom normal</button>
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('result').style.zoom=1.5;this.blur();">Zoom in</button>
    <br />
    </div>
    <div id='help'>Tap the middle of the screen to select an image for the computer to guess.</div>
    <div id='inputDIV' onclick="document.getElementById('iPUT').style.opacity=0.5"><input type="file" id='iPUT' accept="image/*" capture="camera"></div>
    <img id='result' src=''/>
    <script src='index.js'></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've no clue of javascript, but can i run this without the button?

Comment: Yes, just place the code in a separate function and you can call the function without listening for the input change